# Trying to load a faces servlet into an embedded Tomcat but getting class not found

Tags: java, tomcat, myfaces

In my servlet, which has been added to an embedded Tomcat, I'm getting classes not found for some MyFaces factories but not ALL of them. Any idea why this would be? The first in this list is found but the second two are not.

```
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
ParallelWebappClassLoader loader = (ParallelWebappClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class<?> a = loader.loadClass("org.apache.myfaces.context.ExternalContextFactoryImpl");
Class<?> b = loader.loadClass("org.apache.myfaces.context.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl");
Class<?> c = loader.loadClass("org.apache.myfaces.context.LifecycleFactoryImpl");
```

Answer (score 0):

The class paths of the unfound items are erroneous. They are found once corrected.